# How do I disable google cloud print In chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-cloud-print

If I remove a printer from cloud print it tells me to disable the connector to prevent the printers re - registering.  How do I do this?

Comment: How do I do that. It does not appear in the list of extensions?

Comment: "In Chrome, Upper right corner, click on the triple lines --> Settings -->Show Advanced Settings --> Google Cloud Print --> Manage"

Comment: That just gives me the list of printers....